# Convert a cv::Mat (cv::UMat) from 8UC3 to 32FC3 is slow

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::UMat of 8UC3 and I want to convert it to 32FC3.
I use the `convertTo` method offered by the cv::UMat class, but it is slow (I lose more or less 5 frame per second). 
I know that it is due to the conversion uchar -> float, but I was wondering if there exists a method for speeding up such a conversion.

Comment: You're comparing the conversion using UMat with what when you said "I lose more..."?

Comment: I am comparing it with and without using it, just for understanding where the bottleneck is.

Comment: That's normal.. meanwhile make sure that you've activated optimization and you use the latest version of opencv

Comment: Yes, I know that it is normal, but I was wondering only if there are other ways to speed up the process. I already activated all the optimization. But I am open to other suggestions.